# How do I call functions and commands from .vim files in Vader tests?

Tags: vimscript

I am trying to write tests using [Vader plugin](https://github.com/junegunn/vader.vim) but unfortunately, every time I try to invoke a `command`/`function` in `Execute`/`Do` block it doesn't see seems to work on the text provided in **Given** block!

```
# contents of myplugin.vim

function! WrapLastWord(delimiter)
  execute "normal! Bi" . a:delimiter . "\<ESC>ea" . a:delimiter
endfunction

command! -nargs=0 -buffer Bold :call WrapLastWord('*')
```

Contents of `.vader` file

```
Given ('Sample sentence'):
  This is a sample

Do ('bold'):
  A sentence\<ESC>
  :source ../myplugin.vim\<cr>
  :Bold\<CR>

Expect ('Asterisk wrapping around last word'):
  This is a sample *sentence*
```

I have tried some alternatives like below but none of them seems to be making any change on text provided in **Given** block?

```
Execute:
  Bold
```

And Vader raises failures like below

```
  - Expected:
      This is a sample *sentence*
  - Got:
      This is a sample sentence
```

However, if I write the function's instructions in Vader **Do** block (normal mode `Bi*\<esc>ea*`) it works as expected and tests passes.

- Why am I not able to run the same instructions when called from a function/ command written in another file? What am I doing wrong?
- How do I double check and make sure if Vader is able to source the file and function properly?
- Is there a better solution to testing vim plugins/scripts?

**PS:** Any additional help/resource/link to content on automated testing vim plugins would be highly appretiated

Comment: You shouldn't be sourcing your plugin in the Do block, it should be loaded up in the `rtp` before Vader is run. That will bite you in many ways. Also `A` isn't a command you can execute, it's a normal mode keystroke. You'll want to use an alternative to get the Execute bit working.